# How to increment a variable when strstr finds the specified string

Tags: c, strstr

I'm wanting to have my variable houseTot increment by one every time strstr finds a string with "house" in it. I've essentially done this in my code:

```
struct Owner1_def
{
    int totProps;
    char type[40];
    float monthlyPrice;
    float maintenance;
    int bedrooms;
    int bathrooms;
};
typedef struct Owner1_def Owner1;
int main(void)
{
char *ptr;
int i = 0;
ptr = strstr(database[i].hometype, "house");
for(i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
{
if (ptr != NULL)
    houseTot++;
}
return 0;
}
```

But when the program prints houseTot's value, it's still at it's initialized value 0. I don't know much about strstr, but from what I've read, this should work.

Comment: You'll need to supply more code than that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Shouldn't the call to `strstr()` be inside the loop? Is this actual code?

Comment: @DavidBowling that fixed my issue; strstr() is totally new to me and all of the examples I looked at didn't use it in any kind of loop, so I was guessing, thanks!

Comment: strstr returns substring if it is available. So your code should work fine. Printf the database to see if it contain house and supply more code

Answer (score 0):

The call to `strstr()` should be moved inside the loop so that the value stored in `database[i].hometype` can be checked on each iteration:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 3; ++i) {
    ptr = strstr(database[i].hometype, "house");
    if (ptr != NULL)
        houseTot++;
}
```

Note that posted code has no definition for the array of `struct`s `database[]`, and the `struct` provided has no `hometype` field.